Datatable column filter like Excel column filter
I am using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. I have a table like this:
<div class="card-body">
   <table class="table display table-bordered" id="DATATABLE"></table>         
</div>

I am looking for a way to have a column header like this:

I have tried the following code without success:
$("#DATATABLE").DataTable({
  serverSide: true,
  filter: true,
  searchDelay: 1000,
  scrollY: StaticData.TABLE_HEIGHT + 'px',
  lengthMenu: StaticData.TABLE_PAGE_SIZE,            
  scrollCollapse: true,
  ajax: {
    url: '/STUD_MANAGEMENT/LoadStudents',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'json',
    headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': 'your json token' },                
    dataSrc: (json) => {
      json = json.data;

      for (let i = 0, ien = json.length; i < ien; i++) {
        json[i]['isactive'] = '<input type="checkbox">';
      }
      return json;
    }
  },
  columnDefs: [{ className: "dt-center", targets: [7], width: '2%', }],
  columns: [
    { data: 'STUD_ID', title: 'STUD ID', autoWidth: false, visible : false },
    { data: 'NAME', title: 'Name', autoWidth: true },
    { data: 'CLASS', title: 'Class', autoWidth: true },             
    { data: 'isactive', title: 'Is Active ?', autoWidth: false, orderable: false },                
    { data: 'USER', title: 'User', autoWidth: true },
    { data: 'DATE', title: 'Date', autoWidth: true },               
  ],
});


you could try this below code to implement the filter on active non active field:
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataTable = $("#DATATABLE").DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    filter: true,
    searchDelay: 1000,
    scrollY: StaticData.TABLE_HEIGHT + 'px',
    lengthMenu: StaticData.TABLE_PAGE_SIZE,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    ajax: {
      url: '/STUD_MANAGEMENT/LoadStudents',
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'json',
      headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': 'your json token' },
      dataSrc: function(json) {
        json = json.data;
        for (var i = 0, ien = json.length; i < ien; i++) {
          // Set the checkbox to be checked if Is_Active is true
          json[i]['isactive'] = '<input type="checkbox" ' + (json[i].Is_Active ? 'checked' : '') + '>';
        }
        return json;
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{ className: "dt-center", targets: [7], width: '2%' }],
    columns: [
      { data: 'STUD_ID', title: 'StudID', autoWidth: false, visible: false },
      { data: 'NAME', title: 'Name', autoWidth: true },
      { data: 'CLASS', title: 'Class', autoWidth: true },
      { data: 'isactive', title: 'Is Active?', autoWidth: false, orderable: false },
      { data: 'USER', title: 'User', autoWidth: true },
      { data: 'DATE', title: 'Date', autoWidth: true },
    ],
    headerCallback: function(thead, data, start, end, display) {
      $(thead).find('th').eq(3).html(
        '<div>' +
          '<input type="checkbox" id="filter-active" /> Active<br>' +
          '<input type="checkbox" id="filter-non-active" /> Non Active<br>' +
          '<input type="checkbox" id="filter-all" checked /> ALL' +
        '</div>'
      );
    },
    drawCallback: function(settings) {
      //Code to update checkbox state based on current filters
    }
  });

  $(document).on('change', '#filter-active', function() {
    // Apply filter for active
  });

  $(document).on('change', '#filter-non-active', function() {
    // Apply filter for non-active
  });

  $(document).on('change', '#filter-all', function() {
    // Apply filter for all
  });

  // Handle row checkbox changes if needed
  $('#DATATABLE tbody').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    //Get row data
    var data = dataTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    //Change Is_Active status
    var isActive = this.checked;
    //AJAX call to update the server-side data
    console.log('Student ID: ' + data.STUD_ID + ' is now ' + (isActive ? 'active' : 'non-active'));
    //Server update code
  });
});


Thanks. I have one more issue here. I have a Is_Active boolean property in the Student class. How we can data bind to the checkbox (not in the header filter) ? but in the code - json[i]['isactive'] = ''

@JerryMon check the updated code. let me know if you have any concern
